# C++ fast library for drawing 2d with transparency

Tags: c++, graphics, 2d, polygon, getpixel

I'am looking for fast library too make some 2d drawings. I need only to draw polygons, change transparency of them. I don't want to display result in any window, saving to file will be enoght (faster = better)  - I want to learn my algorithm how to draw shapes so i need only methods like "drawPolygon" and "getPixel" to compare results.

Comment: How about good old OpenGL? Or perhaps D3D if you're on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) would also be a valid choice for doing something basic like this.

Comment: It doesn't properly support transparency: it has RGBA images, but doesn't support alpha blending.

Answer (score 0):

The [`GD`](http://www.boutell.com/gd/) library is ideal for drawing shapes onto bitmaps.